# Red5 Server Truncating Recordings

Tags: red5

I'm working on an app that captures a webcam stream and records it via a Red5 server. On my local installation (Red5 version 1, Mac OSX) everything runs perfectly however using the same version of Red5 on Ubuntu (our server enviroment) the video recording is truncated. A 2 min recording turns out to be just over 1 minute, however on the Mac its exactly the expected time.

Could it be as as simple as a config issue or is the 1.0 version of Red5 not stable on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a bug with the current version of Red5. Downgrading to version 0.8 solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an OS issue but an issue with how Red5 handles recording over slow connections.

You have Mac OSX installed locally and when recording to local there is no bandwidth limit. As soon as you use the Ubuntu server, you're streaming (uploading) the audio and video data to a remote server and inherently you have some bandwidth limitations. If you go over these limits the resulting .flv file can have all sorts of issues.

Different Red5 versions have different issues with the recording process. These issues are well documented here: [Recording issues with Red5](http://hdfvr.com/documentation#part11) .

**The best Red5 version for recording** is a patched 1.0.2 version available in this blog post: [Recording high quality (HD) video over slow connections with Red5 is now possible](http://nusofthq.com/blog/recording-high-quality-hd-video-over-slow-connections-with-red5-is-now-possible/)

[The patch has also been applied to Red5's source code on GitHub](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/commit/7e4253f577a88d50613900986a46e5a915859123) and it will be available in the next official build as well (1.0.3).