# video recording issue in AS3 in Red5 server

Tags: actionscript-3, video-recording

I'm using Action Script as client side having Red5 Media Server. I've 2 issues with my video:

1. Video is not recording properly and not playing smoothly.
2. Sometimes video start from 15-20 seconds rather starting from 0 second.

I've written the following code:

```
   private function onStart():void
 {  

  mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
  cam = Camera.getCamera();

  if(cam!=null)
  {
   cam.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onDivStatus);
   ns.attachCamera(cam)
   cam.setQuality( 0, 100 );;


  }
  else
  {
   trace("you need to check webcam setting:");

  }
  if(mic != null)
  {
   mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
   mic.setSilenceLevel(5, 1000);
   mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onDivStatus);
   ns.attachAudio(mic);
  }
  else
  {
   trace("you need to check Microphone setting:");
  }


  webCamRecording.video1.attachCamera(cam);
  webCamRecording.video1.smoothing = true;

}
 var timer:Timer;
 public function startRecording():void
 {
  ns.publish(webCamRecording.userName,"record"); 
  webCamRecording.stopBtn.visible = true;
  webCamRecording.stopBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,stopRecording)
  timer = new Timer(1000,10*60);
  timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
  timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onComplete);
  timer.start(); 
 }

 private function stopRecording(evt:MouseEvent):void
 {
  trace("call external function::::::::::::::D>>>>>> ");
  timer.stop();
  webCamRecording.video1.clear();
     ns = null
     webCamRecording.video1.visible = false;

  }
```

I've checked the logs and find the below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:236)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:68)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:205)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeTag(FLVWriter.java:254)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeMetadataTag(FLVWriter.java:371)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeTag(FLVWriter.java:226)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.write(FileConsumer.java:333)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.doWrites(FileConsumer.java:292)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer$1.run(FileConsumer.java:180)
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:236)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:68)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:205)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeTag(FLVWriter.java:254)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.write(FileConsumer.java:333)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.doWrites(FileConsumer.java:292)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer$1.run(FileConsumer.java:180)
Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
        at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:519)
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.putInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:366)
        at org.apache.mina.core.buffer.AbstractIoBuffer.putInt(AbstractIoBuffer.java:743)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeTag(FLVWriter.java:251)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.write(FileConsumer.java:333)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.doWrites(FileConsumer.java:292)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer$1.run(FileConsumer.java:180)
Exception in thread "Thread-18" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:357)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:336)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:60)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:205)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeTag(FLVWriter.java:254)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.write(FileConsumer.java:333)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.doWrites(FileConsumer.java:292)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer$1.run(FileConsumer.java:180)
Exception in thread "Thread-20" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:236)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:68)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:205)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeTag(FLVWriter.java:254)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.write(FileConsumer.java:333)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.doWrites(FileConsumer.java:292)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer$1.run(FileConsumer.java:180)
Exception in thread "Thread-34" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:236)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:68)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:205)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeTag(FLVWriter.java:278)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.write(FileConsumer.java:333)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.doWrites(FileConsumer.java:292)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer$1.run(FileConsumer.java:180)
Exception in thread "Thread-43" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:236)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:337)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:60)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:205)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeTag(FLVWriter.java:278)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.write(FileConsumer.java:333)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.doWrites(FileConsumer.java:292)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer$1.run(FileConsumer.java:180)
Exception in thread "Thread-44" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:236)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:68)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:205)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeTag(FLVWriter.java:278)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.write(FileConsumer.java:333)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.doWrites(FileConsumer.java:292)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer$1.run(FileConsumer.java:180)
Exception in thread "Thread-48" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:236)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:68)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:205)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeTag(FLVWriter.java:278)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.write(FileConsumer.java:333)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.doWrites(FileConsumer.java:292)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer$1.run(FileConsumer.java:180)
Exception in thread "Thread-65" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:357)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:336)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:60)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:205)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeTag(FLVWriter.java:254)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.write(FileConsumer.java:333)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.doWrites(FileConsumer.java:292)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer$1.run(FileConsumer.java:180)
Exception in thread "Thread-68" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:236)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:68)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:205)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeTag(FLVWriter.java:278)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.write(FileConsumer.java:333)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.doWrites(FileConsumer.java:292)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer$1.run(FileConsumer.java:180)
Exception in thread "Thread-71" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:357)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:336)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:60)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:205)
        at org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVWriter.writeTag(FLVWriter.java:254)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.write(FileConsumer.java:333)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer.doWrites(FileConsumer.java:292)
        at org.red5.server.stream.consumer.FileConsumer$1.run(FileConsumer.java:180)
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Close
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Provider disconnect
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Provider disconnect
[INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Provider disconnect
```

Please if anybody has the solution help me out. thanks.

Comment: which version of RED5 are you using?

Comment: We are using 0.9 version.

Comment: I had these kind of issues with v0.9. Changed to v0.8 to make it work.  You may try with v0.8. Check these link where they were suggesting to use v0.8 [link1](https://code.google.com/p/red5/issues/detail?id=42), [link2](http://red5.5842.n7.nabble.com/Red5-0-9-1-recorded-flv-broken-td25368.html) []link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187896/red5-server-truncating-recordings)

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, Red5 does not produce good recordings.

Try some other server like Wowza Developer Server with same flash client and see if you get better results. If you do then it's a Red5 issue and it's easier to switch servers.

You could try some optimisation by increasing buffers and waiting for buffers to upload.

Comment: i agree, we had to move to wowza after spending big amount of time trying to fix recording under Red5.

Answer (score 0):

**Red5 0.9** had a broken recording process altogether.

**Red5 0.8** did it rather well but had no way to account for Flash Player's prioritisation of audio over video data when streaming/recording over slow  connections. So when recording high quality video over slow connections the audio and video in the final file would not be in sync.

**Red5 1.0 RC1** introduced a delayed write mechanism that almost worked.

**Red5 1.0 final, 1.0.1 and 1.0.2** had the delayed write mechanism totally flawed resulting in flv files with 1 video keyframe and the rest only audio when recording over slow connections.

**The best Red5 version for recording is a patched Red5 1.0.2** available in this blog post: [Recording high quality (HD) video over slow connections with Red5 is now possible](http://nusofthq.com/blog/recording-high-quality-hd-video-over-slow-connections-with-red5-is-now-possible/)

[The patch has also been applied to Red5's source code on GitHub](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/commit/7e4253f577a88d50613900986a46e5a915859123) and it will be available in the next official build as well (1.0.3).

I am the author of that patch and I made it to fix Red5 recording once and for all. It works great.